# Problem with space in path, arguments C# to launch python script

Tags: c#, python, path, space

I don't know how can I code the string format to keep the full path with space, because, it is split at each space.
4 arguments:

- C:/MyDoc/Example/MyCSV File 1.csv
- -1
- 20-05-2019
- 7

`python.run_cmd("C:/MyCode.py", "C:/MyDoc/Example/MyCSV File 1.csv -1 20-05-2019 7");`

Function:

```
 public static void run_cmd(string cmd, string args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
        start.FileName = "C:/PRGM/python.exe";
        start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}",cmd, args);
        start.UseShellExecute = false;
        start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.Write(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about wrapping the file name in quotes, you'll need to escape them using a backslash `\`:

```
python.run_cmd("C:/MyCode.py", "\"C:/MyDoc/Example/MyCSV File 1.csv\" -1 20-05-2019 7");
```

or using a [verbatim string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim):

```
python.run_cmd("C:/MyCode.py", @"""C:/MyDoc/Example/MyCSV File 1.csv"" -1 20-05-2019 7");
```